# Using $injector vs injecting a service directly

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering when would you use `$injector.get('someService')` vs injecting that service directly.

Basically, what is the difference of the two code below?

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

/** Difference of this **/
MyController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$route']; // and more services
MyController($rootScope, $route)
{
    /* ... */
}

/** And this **/
MyController.$inject = ['$injector'];
MyController($injector)
{
    var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    var $route     = $injector.get('$route');
    /* and so on */
}
```

If you are not sure what your controller needs, or that you will update it in the future, and you have it refactored, then using `$injector` it is a lot easier to add/remove dependencies.

Comment: Just use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) with your favourite task runner (gulp/grunt) and you won't have to add the injections yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first approach uses dependency injection while the second uses service locator pattern. Dependency injection has the following advantages:

- It makes a component's dependencies explicit. For example, you can look at the constructor function of a controller and immediately know what dependencies it needs. With service locator, you usually have no idea because the controller might invoke the service locator any time.
- It makes unit test easier. For example you can use the `$controller` service to instantiate a controller and feed it with mock objects via the `locals` argument. That's certainly easier than having to define a bunch of AngularJS services or factories so that `$injector` can resolve them. It becomes worse when coupled with #1: you might not be aware of all dependencies a component needs in order to supply all the necessary mocks.

Service locator does offer some flexibility thought. For example, your code might use a service only if it exists, like this:

```
if ($injector.has('serviceA')) $injector.get('serviceA').doSomething() 
else someSomethingElse()
```

With dependency injection, if `serviceA` doesn't exist by the time your component is constructed, you'll get an error.

As to ease of refactoring, I don't think it's difficult to add/remove parameters to the constructor function. As pointed out in a comment to your question, tools like `ngAnnotate` will help make the declaration DRYer.

Therefore, I would just stick with dependency injection and only use service locator when absolutely necessary.

Comment: An interesting difference is that using the underscored method doesn't work with namespaced services. In a project I'm working on we use dot-separated namespaces, but injecting `_ourService.myController_` breaks stuff. When using `$injector.get('ourService.myController')` it does work.